# How to diagnose and resolve nextcloud slowness that occurs only on an admin account?

Tags: apache-2.4, nextcloud

I have Nextcloud v27.0.2 running in Docker (specifically the image [`27.0.2-apache`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/nextcloud/27.0.2-apache)) and notice that when I login as an admin user it takes minutes before each page loads. I had to increase the timeout of the nginx reverse proxy to 5 minutes to not constantly receive 504 errors.

Regular users could browse the instance as usual, no slowdowns occurred there.

I have a docker-compose file that starts up redis, mariadb, and two nextcloud containers (one for the web-app, one for the cron tasks). Nextcloud user data (`/var/www/nextcloud_data`) and the application folder (`/var/www/html`) is persisted using Docker volumes, as is the database.

How can I diagnose and resolve this issue that only occurs with admin users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the nginx reverse proxy logs, the apache webserver logs and the nextcloud logs I could not find anything out of order.
This being Docker, I re-created the containers and re-downloaded the images several times. Unfortunately that did not resolve the issue.

Then I looked into the persistent data and config. I compared the config file (`/var/www/html/config/config.php`) to a backup I had an noticed that the current config contained an extra key `update.secret` with some hashed value.

After backing up and deleting this key and value, re-creating the containers yet again, the slowness dissappeared and my issue was resolved.